# Unity AR camera to render like VR - Mixed reality

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I am currently playing around with Unity. I have a simple question that I can not find and answer for.

I can easily set up an AR session in Unity for iOS and Android using the AR foundation toolkit. But I would like to make the phone camera picture to render in steroscopic like in regular VR thus creating a Mixed Reality project.

I don't want to use the SDK related to Microsoft Hololens since I would like to aim the development for iOS and Android devices.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Premade solution**

Microsoft has a package that aims for mixed reality but it's for Android and iOS: https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity - but this package is huge, and if you have a project already it will be hard to convert to use this package.

**Custom solution**

If you want to create something together for the prototype (although I would not recommend this for production code as it's not optimized) you can use 2 cameras and set them as following

[image: Camera setup]

Create 2 cameras, with slightly offset origin. And use the ViewportRect parameter of the camera to set rendering for two different eyes.

One camera should have (x: 0, y:0, w: 0.5, h: 1) second (x: 0.5, y:0, w: 0.5, h: 1)

Comment: As far as I Know MRTK does not support stereoscopic camera for iOS and Android. It would make the Hololens headset kind of useless.

For custom solution I am thinking of a custom render pipeline? or something like that. I would grab the device camera image and feed it to the Google Cardboard SDK maybe? 

But yeah the current information related to this topic is kind of limited on the net.